# Computer not pinging from the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, home-networking, ping

I am trying to set up DDNS for my machine and it works for the most part. And, I would like to remotely ping to the machine. Now, the DDNS is configured properly and it is taking the IP refresh properly. 
I have changed the firewall settings on my Windows 10 machine to allow ICMP-In traffic so that ping would be ok. But, it just shows Request timed out.
I would also like to add that ping on the LAN works fine, it seems only that the ICMP traffic coming in from the internet is blocked. I am using Windows Defender for the firewall. 
What could be going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Did you configure your router properly that it allows the incoming traffic to go through to your windows machine (port forwarding)? Otherwise even if you set up the computer correctly that it would allow everything you want, the important packages would just be dropped by your router and never reach your pc.

Comment: I am not sure which port I should enable for ICMP traffic. I have always thought it is portless. But thanks for pointing in the right direction and thanks for welcoming!

Comment: To start from the beginning, _which device_ actually holds the public IP address that you're pinging (the one that goes into DDNS)? Is the IP address assigned to your router, or does your computer have a public IP address for itself? (If we're talking IPv4, 99% of the time it won't have one, so it would be the router that's not replying, not the computer.)

Comment: It's the router's public IP, yes you are correct

Comment: Another question – are you using the "DMZ" feature in your router, or are you expecting it to forward traffic to your computer without that?

Comment: it would be nice if DMZ were not to be used, since this will be rolled out to others too

Comment: Right, then you don't have much choice – having 1 public IP address means all the ICMP Echo pings have to go to 1 destination, and that's either _one_ of your computers (with DMZ) or the router itself (without DMZ).

Comment: true, you are right

Answer (score 1):

> I would also like to add that ping on the LAN works fine, it seems only that the ICMP traffic coming in from the internet is blocked. I am using Windows Defender for the firewall.

It's not that the traffic to your PC is specifically blocked, it's more the opposite.

As you mentioned, the IP address that you're trying to ping doesn't actually belong to your computer – it belongs to your router performing NAT, so you're actually pinging your router.

The expected result is that the router itself should send out Echo Reply packets, but it *may* come with its own firewall rules causing it to ignore ICMP Echo pings from outside (many ISPs do this as part of their default configuration). Either way, it's completely normal that it won't forward those pings to any of your LAN machines, so they won't hit the Windows Firewall at all.

(The same applies to any other traffic when living behind NAT: unless it matches either explicit "port forwarding" rules or implicit NAT states, the default result is that the packets get consumed by the router itself, as it's the device being addressed.)

> I am not sure which port I should enable for ICMP traffic. I have always thought it is portless.

ICMP is indeed portless.

Though, despite the term being "*port* forwarding", it *is* possible to have DNAT rules even for "portless" protocols (like ESP or GRE), most home routers just won't offer that as an option. They *do* often offer "DMZ" as a blanket rule for *all* protocols, which would most likely include ICMP Echo packets as well.

But a significant limitation is that without having port numbers, you don't really have the ability to send *some* Echo packets to host A and some to host B – all you can do is forward *all* of them to the same host.

(When ICMP *error* packets arrive, they carry a few bytes of the original packet that triggered the error – most importantly the original port fields – so your router can still associate each ICMP error with e.g. a specific TCP connection and forward it to the correct LAN host.

When ICMP *echo reply* packets arrive, they also have a distinct "ID" value which is rather similar to a port number, although only one instead of two. Still, it helps your router's NAT recognize which LAN host sent the original ICMP Echo request and route the reply back.

But when ICMP *echo requests* (pings) from Internet arrive at the router, it doesn't have enough information to do much with them. Practically there are only two options: either the router forwards *all* ICMP echo requests to *one* LAN host (like with the 'DMZ' feature), or it handles them directly without forwarding (i.e. the router itself responds).

Comment: I cannot upvote yet, but thanks for your answer